# Adding a mixin causes LookupError while making migrations

Tags: django

**Djanto 1.11**

Could you help me understand what is going on here.

When I comment the mixin out (see below - working subtitle), everything works.

I mean:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Adding a mixin seems to ruin everything.

**tree**

```
.
│
├── frame_person
│   ├── frame_person
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

**settings**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'frame_person.frame_person',
]
```

**Working:**

```
class FramePerson(#CommonUrlMethodsMixin,                  
                  models.Model):
    dd = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Not working**

```
class FramePerson(CommonUrlMethodsMixin,
                  models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 177, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 47, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 152, in _detect_changes
    model = self.new_apps.get_model(al, mn)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 205, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 172, in get_model
    "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'frame_person' doesn't have a 'frameperson' model.
(photoarchive) michael@ThinkPad:~/workspace/photoarchive_project/photoarchive$ python manage.py makemigrations --settings=config.settings.local
```

**CommonUrlMethodsMixin**

```
class CommonUrlMethodsMixin():
    """
    Models for applications whose urls can be resolved from the 
    application name and object pk:

    frame_general:frame_detail,
    frame_general:frame_update    
    """

    def _get_url_helper(self, suffix):
        """
        suffix - str.

            Suffix choices:
                1) detail;
                2) update;
                3) delete;

        Prepares reverse string depending on what view we need.
        """
        app = self._meta.app_label

        return reverse("{0}:{1}".format(app, suffix),
                       kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self._get_url_helper("detail")

    def get_update_url(self):
        return self._get_url_helper("update")

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return self._get_url_helper("delete")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**ADDED LATER**

The code below works:

```
class CommonUrlMethodsMixin():
    """
    Models for applications whose urls can be resolved from the 
    application name and object pk:

    frame_general:frame_detail,
    frame_general:frame_update    
    """

    def _get_url_helper(self, suffix):
        """
        suffix - str.

            Suffix choices:
                1) detail;
                2) update;
                3) delete;

        Prepares reverse string depending on what view we need.
        """
        app = self._meta.app_label

        return reverse("{0}:{1}".format(app, suffix),
                       kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self._get_url_helper("detail")

    def get_update_url(self):
        return self._get_url_helper("update")

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return self._get_url_helper("delete")

    # class Meta:
    #     abstract = True
```

I just commented out "abstract = True". I can't understand this. Can't this class be abstract?